# if we return non-zero value in main function, why doesn't it show any type of error

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("hello world");
  return 55;
}
```

I was reading an article that. The return value of main() function shows how the program exited. The normal exit of program is represented by zero return value. If the code has errors, fault etc., it will be terminated by non-zero value.

Since I am returning an non-zero value to main function. I assume that it must show errors(because I am not returning 0 to main function), but when i compliled and executed it.It didn't show any errors and it executed normally.Can you please explain it why? In advance thank you

Answer (score 5):

Your assumption is wrong, the surrounding environment (the shell in Linux, command prompt in Windows, your IDE, or whatever you use to start the program) does *not* by default check the status so nothing happens.

If in Linux, you can do

```
$ ./myprog
$ echo $?
```

and you should see `55`.

Update: In Windows, I just learned that you can use `errorlevel`:

```
$ .\myprog
$ echo %errorlevel%
```

Comment: Re “It would become very messy very quickly if the shell reacted to the exit status of programs”: No, it would not. I have had my shell set to print non-zero exit statuses for about two decades, and it has not become messy yet, let alone very messy. To the contrary, it is useful to know when a process has indicated a problem.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'll take one instance of anecdata over my base-less hunch any day of the week, edited. Thanks.